# Possible to create UIWindow to cover up auto segues from push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I am getting a data packet from push notification in my app delegate. If I get this push, I want to segue to appropriate view controller which is a a few VCs deep in my nav stack. It looks really choppy watching the app quickly segue 4 or 5 times to get to appropriate VC.

It looks like I want to create a new UIWindow to cover up my main window while this choppy transition happens. How can I do this with a new UIWindow (have it appear when we know a push is coming through and remove when we reach correct view controller)? Is there another better way to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just segue directly to the target view controller. If you are using a navigation controller then you can manipulate the view controller stack after the fact so that "back" works correctly

Comment: Thanks for the response @Paulw! What methods are you using to programmatically add VCs to the stack after the fact? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use another `UIWindow` to initiate this nav stack transition, all you'd have to do is in your application's `keyWindow`, show some kind of "progress" indication while the transitions are happening in a background window, and then all you'd have to do is set the `keyWindow` property on your `AppDelegate`. You can also transition this "setting" with whatever animation you'd like!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BHendricks! How are you creating a new window in the app delegate, and then removing it on some other view controller? Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: A UIWindow can be initiated from any class, just specify it's frame that you want :) and you just need to access the AppDelegate's keyWindow property, so to get that from a viewController you'd do UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate (in swift) to get a reference to your AppDelegate.